# Chain linq Any() method to find json

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have the following Json in a json.net JObject:

```
{ project: [
         {
             allBuilds: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, { id:3, id:4,}]
         },
         {
             allBuilds: [{id: 5}, {id: 6}, { id:7, id:8,}]
         }
        ]
}
```

If I have an array of projects how do I find the project that contains a certain id?
I tried:

```
var matchingProject = arrayOfProjects.FirstOrDefault(project => 
project["allBuilds"].Any(build => (int) build["id"] == 5))
```

Comment: And what's wrong with your approach? It looks fine to me. p.s., you have objects that define `id` multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a concrete class that you can deserialize the json into.
You can use JavaScripSerializer to do this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/210810/Deserialize-JSON-with-C

I don't think you can use LINQ with dynamic objects directly since your data structure has to be an `IEnumerable<T> for LINQ to work.`

On your serialized object try this:

```
var found = project.SelectMany(b => b.allBuilds).Any(a => a.Id == 5);
```

Comment: Do you have any examples of chaining the Any() method if I do decide to deserialize the json into a class?

Comment: Json.net parses json into iEnumerable JObjects and JTokens. I was spelling the properties wrong, that's why my LINQ statements were not working.  Spelling mistakes is probably a good reason to deserialize into concrete class.  Thanks.